# Update bids (current price ) for android clients instantly and continuously from server

Tags: android, synchronization, webserver, client-server, instant

I'm designing an online auction system in which android clients give bids to an item and bids are going to save in my database on server.

I want to update current price of an item on all android clients and show them current bid or price of a merchandise.
In fact, clients must be informed of latest bid (proposed price)  represented from other users "Instantly" in order of seconds ( as soon as possible! ).

What is the best solution for updating or syncing an item price adopted from server and showing them instantly on android clients? 
I want a practical solution for this purpose.

Comment: I think socket layer programming as done for many messaging app. Famous is WhatsApp

Comment: I assume it increases resources consumption in both server and client sides. I think of a upper level solution. Besides, WhatsApp is a messaging app mine is rather different.

Comment: I am an Android developer cannot tell related to backend scalable and feasible solutions. But for Android you can use it

Comment: Ok , could you post a sample code for what you've proposed?

Comment: Check this out: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: Thanks Jimit , But I want a solution containing appropriate provided libraries such as Volley , Sync Adapter and etc or mixture of them!

Comment: There is another library. I have not used it but have heard of it. Check it if it's of your use: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Comment: Unfortunately that library you've suggested it's not about synchronization problem which I try to find a solution for it!